# blank page between section and figures

Tags: floats, page-breaking, page, appendix

I am trying to create an Appendix for my experiment figures, and the following is the my code

```
\section{}\label{sec:figures}

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}  
        ...
    \end{minipage}      
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}  
        ...
    \end{minipage}      
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}  
        ...
    \end{minipage}      
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}  
        ...
    \end{minipage}      
\end{figure*}
```

There is unintentional blank page inserted between the section title and the figures like the following.

[image]

How can I make latex not do this unintentional page break?
Thanks.

Update:
I have tried using the float package with

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}  
        ...
    \end{minipage}      
\end{figure}
```

The problem with this is that I am using a two-column format and this made the picture overlay on each other.

Comment: It seems like you want to place the images in-place, rather than have them float. For that, consider adding the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) to your preamble and use `\begin{figure}[H]`...`\end{figure}` instead of `\begin{figure*}`...`\end{figure*}`. Regardless, the principle of this question is solved by [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: I have tried using the float package. The problem with that is that I am using a two-column format and this made the picture overlay on each other.

Comment: So that's why you're using `figure*`, to get the picture to span two columns. `figure*` is known to place content at the top of *the following* page. I think you should be more clear in your description of what you have and what you want. Perhaps, provide the community with a minimal working example (MWE) that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you have. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and use packages like [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) for text and `example-image` for inclusion of images. Can you do that?